# jquery-UI Dialog resize issue

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to create a "docked" dialog using jquery-ui dialog, and I'm having some issues resizing it.

I have docked it using css when the dialog opens to give it fixed position and appropriate sizing.

```
$("#test").dialog({
    open: function() {
        $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
               .css({"float": "right",
                     "position": "fixed",
                     "right": "0px",
                     "left": "auto",
                     "top": "0px",
                     "height":  $(window).height() + "px"                       
                })
    }
```

The problem I have is that I can make it narrower (by dragging the left edge of the dialog), but I can't make it wider.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqa5Lsns/3/).

Any help, suggestions would be most appreciated.  Or even a better way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Your fiddle works for me on Firefox 42.0. No issues making the docked dialog wider.

Comment: So it does :) Thanks for investigating.  I should have mentioned I was trying in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Add width: auto in the CSS of the dialog configuration. Like so

```
...
"top": "0px",
"width": "auto",
"height":  $(window).height() + "px"        
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tqa5Lsns/5/

Tried in Chome. The maximum width is limited by the dialog content.

Comment: Inside the css block in the open callback?

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried adding this, but I still cannot make the dialog wider than the initial view.  Am I missing something?  Are you using Chrome?